# Unable to connect to Redis Server when using apache beam sdk

Tags: redis, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

So I have a dataflow job doing

```java
p.apply(RedisIO.read()
    .withEndpoint(<public endpoint>, 6379)
    .withAuth(<password>)
    .withTimeout(60000)
    .withKeyPattern("UID*"))
 .apply(ParDo.of(new Format()))
 .apply(TextIO.write().to(options.getOutput()));
```

The redis endpoint is public authenticated with a password with no firewall settings. When I run the above, I get the following error.

```java
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven- 
plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project word-count-beam: An 
exception occured while executing the Java class. 
org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to 
execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default- 
cli) on project word-count-beam: An exception occured while executing 
the Java class. org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception 
occured while executing the Java class. 
org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:339)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.beam.runners.direct.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent 
.UncheckedExecutionException: 
org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

So connection is not getting established with public redis endpoint. I am getting the same error when I am running through **DirectRunner**. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Can you confirm that the connection works outside of the Apache Beam context? For example, can you connect with the `redis-cli` tool?

Comment: Yes, I can do that @Andrew

Answer (score 0):

There is a known error in the Apache Beam source code for RedisIO where withEndpoint ignores the input host and will attempt to use localhost instead. Attempting to connect to a redis server on localhost when there is none will give the error you are seeing.

You can read more about the issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3314), and see a pull request with a fix [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/4228).

Until that pull request gets merged you should be able to resolve the problem by implementing the change yourself by copying [RedisIO.java](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/redis/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/redis/RedisIO.java) into your project and changing

```
.setConnectionConfiguration(connectionConfiguration().withHost(host))
.setConnectionConfiguration(connectionConfiguration().withPort(port))
```

to

```
.setConnectionConfiguration(connectionConfiguration().withHost(host).withPort(port))
```

Note this same error occurs 3 times in RedisIO, once each for Read (line 168), ReadAll (line 233), and Write (line 365).